# Elastic search querying using rest

Tags: java, rest, elasticsearch

I am trying to execute below query in elastic search using rest call which is not providing aggregation results.But if i excute the same query in elasticsearch browser it provides aggregation results.

Query:

```
{ "aggregations": { "by_salary": { "terms": { "field": "salary" } } } }
```

Rest call:

```
http://localhost:9200/tcx_transaction/_search?query={ "aggregations": { "by_salary": { "terms": { "field": "salary" } } } }
```

Results:

```
"aggregations": {
    "by_salary": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "manager",
                "doc_count": 39420
            }
            ,
            {
                "key": "developer",
                "doc_count": 13140
            }
            ,
            {
                "key": "HR",
                "doc_count": 4380
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: "Using rest call" - you mean using something simple like curl?

Comment: The "query" as you're showing it should be the request _body_ and not a query string parameter as you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing the REST interface. Take a peek at the [parameters allowed for URI searching](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html#_parameters_4). `query` isn't one of them. `q` is but that is specifically for a very [special type of query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html).

As pickypg mentioned, what you have set to `query` should be part of the HTTP POST body.

Answer (score 0):

try installing "curl" and then, from shell:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/tcx_transaction/_search' -d 
'{ "aggregations": { "by_salary": { "terms": { "field": "salary" } } } }'
```